# context error- The entity type ApplicationUser is not part of the model for the current context

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity, owin

Well, I have tried many things without any  help. 
The situation is if I have my connection string as a regular connection string for example:

```
<add name="MyConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=mydatasource;Connection Lifetime=10;Max Pool Size=800;Initial Catalog=mydb;Persist Security Info=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;User ID=myuser;Password=mypass" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I have this error:

```
The context is being used in Code First mode with code that was generated from an EDMX file for either Database First or Model First development.  This will not work correctly. To fix this problem do not remove the line of code that throws this exception. If you wish to use Database First or Model First, then make sure that the Entity Framework connection string is included in the app.config or web.config of the start-up project. If you are creating your own DbConnection, then make sure that it is an EntityConnection and not some other type of DbConnection, and that you pass it to one of the base DbContext constructors that take a DbConnection. To learn more about Code First, Database First, and Model First see the Entity Framework documentation here: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=394715
```

and the error comes from here:

```
public partial class myConnectionString : DbContext
{
    public myConnectionString()
        : base("name=myConnectionString")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();// error comes from here
    }

    public virtual DbSet<AspNetRoles> AspNetRoles { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<AspNetUserClaims> AspNetUserClaims { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<AspNetUserLogins> AspNetUserLogins { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<AspNetUsers> AspNetUsers { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<ConnectedUsers> ConnectedUsers { get; set; }
}
```

If I have the EF connection string. for example:

```
    <add name="myConnectionString" connectionString="metadata=res://*/HdkDb.csdl|res://*/HdkDb.ssdl|res://*/HdkDb.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=mydatasource;initial catalog=mydb;user id=myuser;password=mypass;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

I have this error:

```
The entity type ApplicationUser is not part of the model for the current context.
```

and the error comes from here:

```
 var user = UserManager.Find(email, password);
```

this is what I have in my startup.auth.cs

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // Configure the db context and user manager to use a single instance per request
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);

        // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
        // and to use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
        // Configure the sign in cookie
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                    regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
            }
        });

        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
}
```

**Things to be noted:**
I have Entity framework (EDMX) in one project, Authentication (IdentityModel, Usermanager) in another project. And I have using it from another MVC 5 project(where I have the startup.auth.cs).
In all of the projects app/web config, I have the same connection string.

How would I solve this? any help !!

Comment: You can't mix entities from two different contexts in one LINQ query.

Comment: But I am not doing that !!

Comment: Fair enough, but I don't know what you do. Where does the exception occur? (method + line)

Comment: updated my question with the specific point where the error comes from

Comment: The two issues are completely unrelated, and the first issue is no issue anymore. So you better remove all redundant text from your question. For the remaining issue: how do you instantiate `UserManager`?

Comment: I am actually trying to solve the first one. When you say no issue anymore, what do you mean actually?

Comment: I think he means to say the first connection string is wrong. The second connection string is the one you want.